# DD Authentication - How do I keep my credentials secure?

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-management, multi-factor

The future is here. The good folks over at Stack Overflow [will soon release new forms of authentication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/30/stack-overflow-unveils-next-steps-computer-security/?cb=1), namely DDA, SSA, and BBA.

Using it at home is perfectly reasonable since most of our homes are (hopefully) secure. But then, given that these new authentication methods are also meant to be used in public, how am I supposed to guard it, given that various cameras and microphones are virtually everywhere? (CCTVs, smartphones, etc.)

Passwords are pretty easy to type discreetly, or can be inputted using a password manager. OTPs expire after a few seconds. DDA is not discreet, and also does not expire.

Comment: What's the point? It will get deleted anyway. If someone wanted to write an ironic answer, they could do it in the comments to the blog post or YouTube video. At least it will prevail there.